# Can I virtualize existing Android device?

Tags: settings, factory-reset, virtualization

Is there any way to convert existing Android device into virtual machine?

I'm going to do factory reset and pretty sure that some valuable passwords etc. will be lost after it. That's why it would be great to have old data saved in virtual machine on PC so that later these forgotten info can be accessed.

Comment: @cybersam, that question you mention is focused on several applications (WeChat, WhatsApp), while my doesn't mention any particular app.

Comment: @SergiyKheylyk The answer on that question though is applicable to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using BlueStack it will emulate an android on your pc so you can use your preferred method of backup and put it on BlueStack i would recommend titanium backup